# return statement that returns nothing in recursion

Tags: javascript

I found this code about recursion online

```
function countDownRecursive(n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    console.log('Hooray')
    return
  }

  console.log(n)
  countDownRecursive(n - 1)
}
```

I am really confused about this code, why does it console.log("Hooray") and then return nothing? Can you explain it to me? Thank you so much.

Comment: How do you know what it returns? You never examine the return value from `countDownRecursive`.

Comment: Returning does/means two things: It makes the execution flow return from the function to its caller, i.e. prematurely stops its execution before reaching the end, and it also sets _which value_ is returned from the function to its caller - if none is set, that's `undefined` just like it would be when reaching the end of the function normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does it console.log("Hooray")

Because the function is recursive and when you start with let's say `n=1` the function will not print "Hooray" immediately, because the condition:

```js
if (n <= 0)
```

does not apply i.e. is `false`.

By the time we reach the recursion:

```
countDownRecursive(n - 1)
```

We call the function again with `n=0` due to `n - 1`, the if-statement will evaluate to `true` and therefore print "Hooray".

> and then return nothing

It does not actually return "nothing", even though the return type is `void`, it returns `undefined`, which is the default behavior for `return` you could also write `return undefined` instead.

When you use `return`, it will basically terminate or return from the current function. It will jump back into the scope where you did call the function initially.

Hope that clears it up for you.

Answer (score 2):

you returned a null value, the function output type is void.
try this

```
if (n <= 0) {
    console.log('Hooray')
    return n
  }
```

Comment: This still won't return a value for values of `n` greater than `0` as the value returned by the recursive call is never returned.

Comment: Does not have to! the idea of recursion is to call the function inside itself.
the call stack is like :
`countDownRecursive -> countDownRecursive -> ...`
and each function return value is returned to the upper function in the call stack.

Comment: It does have to if you want a value returned. "and each function return value is returned to the upper function in the call stack" only if the called function returns the value. With `countDownRecursive -> countDownRecursive* -> ...` the "nested" `countDownRecursive*` does not return it's value to `countDownRecursive` function.

Comment: You can see this if you run the code with your proposed changes, it logs undefined: https://jsfiddle.net/8eqnx7sc/

Answer (score 2):

`return` in this context means *you don't want to continue running the function* (similar to `break` in iterations).

The above recursive function's logic can be converted to this below `while` logic.

```js
let n = 3;
//iterate until found the while break
while (true) {
  //the condition to stop
  if (n <= 0) {
    console.log('Hooray');
    break; //stop `while`
  }
  console.log(n)
  n = n - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it with an example. This is the hierarchy of the calls when n = 5

```
countDownRecursive(5) // "5"
  countDownRecursive(4) // "4"
    countDownRecursive(3) // "3"
      countDownRecursive(2) // "2"
        countDownRecursive(1) // "1"
          countDownRecursive(0) // "Hooray" because n == 0, we execute the return statement
          end of countDownRecursive(0) because of return
        end of countDownRecursive(1) because reaching the end
      end of countDownRecursive(2) because reaching the end
    end of countDownRecursive(3) because reaching the end
  end of countDownRecursive(4) because reaching the end
end of countDownRecursive(5) because reaching the end
```

The returns statement tells the program to stop calling itself